# Is "to say something from someone" an English idiom?

Tags: prepositions, idioms, usage

I would like to know if it is acceptable to say something like...

> You shouldn't be saying that from your wife!

Or

> How can you say such a thing from your friend?

I know that "of" and "about" are the standard prepositions to be used, but I've seen and heard "from" being used sometimes, and I wonder if the use of the preposition "from" is also acceptable.

Comment: Your statements are NOT idiomatic. In fact, it's hard to know what they might mean.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition "from" isn't idiomatic.  It doesn't mean the same as "about".

It would seem to suggest that the saying is coming from your friend, but it is you that is saying...  which is a contradiction.  Ultimately I would not know what you mean by this.